# How to install md5sum in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, hashsum

I am using FreeBSD 11.1

I am unable to find right way to install `md5sum` package in FreeBSD installation. I need `md5sum` for Conda installation.

Please suggest if you know anyways.

Answer (score 7):

`md5sum` is part of GNU coreutils.  The FreeBSD port to install is `sysutils/coreutils`.  This will install all the GNU coreutils with a `g` prefix, so `md5sum` will be available as `gmd5sum`.

How to install ports/packages is described in [the FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports.html).

---

It is common to install GNU coreutils with a `g` prefix on non-Linux systems as some of the utilities' names clash with the native base system utilities.  NetBSD installs the utilities both with a `g` prefix *and* without the prefix but under a separate path, `.../gnu/bin`.

FreeBSD also has [a `md5` utility](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=md5&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).  This is also available on other BSDs.